# C - Printing the head of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, printf

I am trying to build a linked list from a string of integers separated by spaces. Each integer in the string will be added to the linked list except for -1. However, when I try to print the data in the head node of the list, I get the error `Member reference base type 'Node *' (aka 'struct node *') is not a structure or union`. Why can't I print `head_ptr`'s data in that line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
  int data;
  Node *next;
};


void build_linked_list(Node **head_ptr) {
  char *string = malloc(1028);
  char *p = string, *found = string;
  Node *nextNode = NULL;
  if (fgets(string, 1028, stdin) != NULL) {
    while ((found = strsep(&p, " \n")) != NULL) {
      if (strcmp(found, "-1") == 1) {
        Node node = {atoi(found), nextNode};
        nextNode = &node;
      }
    }
  }
  *head_ptr = nextNode;
  printf("%i\n", *head_ptr->data); // can't print data in head node
  free(string);
}

int main() {
  Node *head = NULL;
  build_linked_list(&head);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The `->` operator has precedence over the dereferencing operator. Since `head_ptr` is `Node**`, the compiler is telling you that `head_ptr->data` is not a thing. If you write `(*head_ptr)->data` it will work (or simply `nextNode->data`). Note also that `nextNode` might be `NULL` after the loop, if the loop doesn't find a match. Also, `&node` will crash your program at some point, since `node` is a variable with automatic duration, and ceases to exist when you exit the block, use `malloc` instead to allocate space for this node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to put parentheses around the head_ptr to make it work, like this: `(*head_ptr)->data)`
the problem arises since the compiler evaluates the expression as a dereference of a double pointer with a member of int, so first it tries to get the int member from the double pointer, which doesn't exist.
so that's why you need to put the parenthesis, so it will evaluate the head_ptr as a dereference of the double pointer, and will use the int member of that struct.